# How to select the location from a field which fetches result from google map api using selenium webdriver(Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[image]

I have tried entering the complete field value using selenium but this doesn't work. It requires to select from the suggestion shown. Anyone knows how to select from the suggestion show.

Note: I am using hybrid framework.

Comment: Unclear. Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like the below one? If yes, replace Thread.sleep with explicit waits.

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/maps?source=tldso");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("searchboxinput")).sendKeys("Kora");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        List<WebElement> autoSuggestions=driver.findElement(By.className("sbsb_b")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        for (WebElement suggestions : autoSuggestions) {
            if (suggestions.getText().contains("Koramangala Police Station")) {
                suggestions.click();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                break;
            }
        }
        driver.quit();
```

Comment: But you can use .equals instead of .contains if your content is subcontant of any larger text. Like if you are looking for 'Koramangala' then .contains can return true for 'Koramangala Police Station'.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sendKeys(Keys.Arrow_Down);`
until the address you need and then use
`sendKeys(Keys.Enter);`